# The series ${\sin (n\pi /10})$ is in class $l^2$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sequence $\{  \sin (\frac{n\pi}{10})\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is in class $l^2$ if the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{10})$ converges.

So we have to check whether $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{10})< \infty$$
My attempt: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin^2(\frac{n\pi}{10})= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2}\cos(\frac{n\pi}{5}))$$
$$= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \cos(\frac{n\pi}{5})$$

From here can i conclude that the series diverges?

Or does it converge? If yes then how?

Comment: Try to sum over the subset n=5,15,25,35,...
Clearly, the total sum can't be smaller than that sum.

Comment: did you mean $\sin\left(\frac{10}{n\pi}\right)$?

Comment: @peek-a-boo no. The question is clear and correct.

Comment: asaelr means: $\sin^2(5\pi/10) = 1$, $\sin^2(15\pi/10) = 1$, $\sin^2(25\pi/10)=1$, and so on.

Comment: @asaelr then the summation in of 1/2 and this sum cancels out and im left with $\frac{-1}{2}\sum_{n=1,n\ne 5,15,25,...}^\infty  cos \frac{n\pi}{5}$.  What can i say about the convergence of this series

Comment: @GEdgar yes i get it. See my previous comment and help me further!!

Comment: No need to compute any sums. $\sum a_n$ cannot converge if $a_n$ does not tend to $0$.